# How to integrate Laravel Billable with custom form?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-5.1

I am reading the docs of [Laravel Billing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/billing#introduction), it does provide classes to be used to make payments etc but no guidance of how to create custom form, what should be the action URL etc.

I don't want to use any .js popup or other thing(*if it's not the only way to deal with it*)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried laracast tutorial for stripe. It's old and some things changed on it since 4.2 was upgraded to 5.1. I am on same boat, and would love to learn custom forms. I have researched and found [This repo](https://github.com/alnutile/sponsors) online. I am not sure, if that helps. But at-least it will get you to look at code and do some custom work. I was able to install and use the api, but still working on a full custom solution.